# Print all worksheet data into userform textbox

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm new in excel VBA, can someone help me understand and tell me how can i print all sheet data to the userform textbox, instead of single column which this code is printing. I have data in the sheet6("Tables") till column AA 360

```
  Dim arr As Variant
  Dim myarr As String
  Dim i As Long
  myarr = Sheets("Tables").Range("A:AA").Value
  For i = LBound(myarr, 1) To UBound(myarr, 1)
       myarr = myarr & myarr(i, 1) & vbCrLf
  Next i
  TextBox1 = myarr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using `ListBox` instead of `TextBox` would be much more useful for you. Add it to `UserForm1` (it is name of your Userform if you haven't changed it) and add values:

```
With UserForm1.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 27
    .ColumnWidths = "50"
    .RowSource = "'Tables'!A1:AA360"
End With
```

You can manipulate value in `.ColumnWidths` to adjust it for your data.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working but only problem.It is taking sheet1 columns and row .Instead of sheet6("Tables"). Commandbtn to display the userform is place in the sheet1

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your concern. As far as I know, there is nothing like `sheet6("Tables")` in VBA. You can have your spreadsheet object named `sheet6` or reference to it by its visible name by `Sheets("Tables")`. I don't know also how you can place userform in some particular sheet and what some Comandbutton has to do with all of this.

Comment: It is not printing the data from Sheet "Tables".Instead printing data from sheet1

Comment: Ok, I have wrongly addressed `.RowSource`, my bad. Check out my post now, after edit.

Comment: If so, please mark my post as an answer, using this green mark on its left.

Comment: One little help. Extra space is coming between the columns. Is there a way to remove the extra space between the columns

Comment: Have you tried to manipulate with `.ColumnWidths`? If yes, please post screenshot of the problem by editing your post. I don't know exactly what spaces are we talking about.